# How do I set color hues for a grouped line chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to set the colors for my ggplot line chart from dark blue to light purple.

I think I might have to use color brewer but I'm not sure the right way to do it

Can I set the high color to some color and the low color to some other color?

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, group = Species)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Try adding  `+ scale_color_gradient(low = "darkblue", high = "purple")`

Comment: I'm using a group = to create my groups

Comment: @Cauder please add a MRE so that we can better help you

Comment: I added in an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scale_color_gradient` will work for continuous data, but not for factors.
You can use `colorRampPalette` to brew your own palette which interpolates any number of desired shades between two chosen colors.

There is no color named 'light purple' in R's default colors so I used one that looked close. Try this code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3

### create color making function
colfunct <- colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "darkorchid1 "))

###  brew desired number of colors, which is 3 for the built-in iris dataset 
shades <- colfunct(3)

### plot the data and map color to the factor of interest
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color=Species))+
  geom_point(shape=1)+
  geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y~x, se=FALSE)+
  scale_color_manual(values =  shades)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @Cauder your example maps "Species" to "group", not to color. Try using `aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color= Species)` and it should work ?